# Importing and updating data in Elasticsearch

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, logstash

We have an existing search function that involves data across multiple tables in SQL Server. This causes a heavy load on our DB, so I'm trying to find a better way to search through this data (it doesn't change very often). I have been working with Logstash and Elasticsearch for about a week using an import containing 1.2 million records. My question is essentially, "how do I update existing documents using my 'primary key'"?

CSV data file (pipe delimited) looks like this:

```
369|90045|123 ABC ST|LOS ANGELES|CA
368|90045|PVKA0010|LA|CA
367|90012|20000 Venice Boulvd|Los Angeles|CA
365|90045|ABC ST 123|LOS ANGELES|CA
363|90045|ADHOCTESTPROPERTY|DALES|CA
```

My logstash config looks like this:

```
input {
  stdin {
    type => "stdin-type"
  }

  file {
    path => ["C:/Data/sample/*"]
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}

filter {
  csv {
    columns => ["property_id","postal_code","address_1","city","state_code"]
    separator => "|"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    embedded => true
    index => "samples4"
    index_type => "sample"
  }
}
```

A document in elasticsearch, then looks like this:

```
{
   "_index": "samples4",
   "_type": "sample",
   "_id": "64Dc0_1eQ3uSln_k-4X26A",
   "_score": 1.4054651,
   "_source": {
   "message": [
      "369|90045|123 ABC ST|LOS ANGELES|CA\r"
   ],
   "@version": "1",
   "@timestamp": "2014-02-11T22:58:38.365Z",
   "host": "[host]",
   "path": "C:/Data/sample/sample.csv",
   "property_id": "369",
   "postal_code": "90045",
   "address_1": "123 ABC ST",
   "city": "LOS ANGELES",
   "state_code": "CA"
}
```

I *think* would like the unique ID in the `_id` field, to be replaced with the value of `property_id`. The idea is that subsequent data files would contain updates. I don't need to keep previous versions and there wouldn't be a case where we added or removed keys from a document.

The `document_id` setting for elasticsearch output doesn't put that field's value into `_id` (it just put in "property_id" and only stored/updated one document). I know I'm missing something here. Am I just taking the wrong approach?

**EDIT: WORKING!**

Using @rutter's suggestion, I've updated the `output` config to this:
`output {
  elasticsearch {
    embedded => true
    index => "samples6"
    index_type => "sample"
    document_id => "%{property_id}"
  }
}`

Now documents are updating by dropping new files into the data folder as expected. `_id` and `property_id` are the same value.
`{
   "_index": "samples6",
   "_type": "sample",
   "_id": "351",
   "_score": 1,
   "_source": {
   "message": [
      "351|90045|Easy as 123 ST|LOS ANGELES|CA\r"
   ],
   "@version": "1",
   "@timestamp": "2014-02-12T16:12:52.102Z",
   "host": "TXDFWL3474",
   "path": "C:/Data/sample/sample_update_3.csv",
   "property_id": "351",
   "postal_code": "90045",
   "address_1": "Easy as 123 ST",
   "city": "LOS ANGELES",
   "state_code": "CA"
}`

Comment: You can overwrite a document by sending another document with the same ID... but that might be tricky with your previous data, since you'll get randomized IDs by default. You can set an ID using the output filter's `document_id` field, but it takes a literal string, not a field name. To use a field's contents, you could use an [sprintf format string](http://logstash.net/docs/1.3.3/configuration#sprintf), such as `%{property_id}`.

Comment: @rutter - Can you create an answer using sprintf format string so I can mark it correct? That worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad that helped! Answer is [posted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21738549/1251354).

Comment: Anothe example using checksums and `%{document_id}`: https://github.com/shurane/GettingStartedWithELK/blob/checksum/Examples/Checksum/checksum.conf

Comment: @EhteshChoudhury your link is broken

Comment: Thanks @sjngm, it's been relocated to https://github.com/coolacid/GettingStartedWithELK/blob/master/Examples/Fingerprint/fingerprint.conf

Comment: "index_type" is deprecated. Use "document_type" now instead. Same effect, better name.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Converting from comment:

You can overwrite a document by sending another document with the same ID... but that might be tricky with your previous data, since you'll get randomized IDs by default.

You can set an ID using the output plugin's [`document_id` field](http://logstash.net/docs/1.3.3/outputs/elasticsearch#document_id), but it takes a literal string, not a field name. To use a field's contents, you could use an [sprintf format string](http://logstash.net/docs/1.3.3/configuration#sprintf), such as `%{property_id}`.

Something like this, for example:

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    ... other settings...
    document_id => "%{property_id}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Working code & output have been added to the question.

Answer (score 1):

declaimer - I'm the author of ESL
You can use [elasticsearch_loader](https://github.com/moshe/elasticsearch_loader) to load psv files into elasticsearch.
In order to set the _id field you can use --id-field=property_id.
for instance:
`elasticsearch_loader --index=myindex --type=mytype --id-field=property_id csv --delimiter='|' filename.csv`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the config to this:

```
filter {
  csv {
    columns => ["_id","postal_code","address_1","city","state_code"]
    separator => "|"
  }
}
```

By naming property_id as _id it should get used during indexing.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I tried this. For whatever reason, it didn't run the import at all.

Comment: This answer in incorrect. It returns the following error : `org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: failed to parse [_id]`