# How to Populate a Elastic Search Index from text file?

Tags: csv, import, elasticsearch

I'm planning to use an Elastic Search index to store an huge city database with ~2.9 milion records, and use it as search engine at my Laravel Application.

The question is: I both have the cities at MySQL database and at CSV File. The file have ~300MB.

How can I import it to a index fastest?

Comment: Almost a duplicate, although [this one is about *re*-populating an index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21716002/importing-and-updating-data-in-elasticsearch). Similar question and similar scale of file size, though.

Comment: @GolezTrol this question don't have a clear answer. I'm not able to extract a solution to my problem from it... :/

Comment: https://kevinkirsche.com/2014/08/25/using-logstash-to-import-csv-files-into-elasticsearch/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've solved this importing using [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash).

My import script is this:

```
input {
      file {
          path => ["/home/user/location_cities.txt"]
          type => "city"
          start_position => "beginning"
      }
}

filter {
    csv {
        columns => ["region", "subregion", "ufi", "uni", "dsg", "cc_fips", "cc_iso", "full_name", "full_name_nd", "sort_name", "adm1", "adm1_full_name", "adm2", "adm2_full_name"]
        separator => "  "
        remove_field => [ "host", "message", "path" ]
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        action => "index"
        protocol => "http"
        host => "127.0.0.1"
        port => "9200"
        index => "location"
        workers => 4
    }
}
```

This script will import a **tab separated** file without delimiters into an index called `location` with type `city`.

To run the script, need to run `bin/logstash -f import_script_file` at the folder that you installed/extracted the Logstash.

Answer (score 0):

For efficiency, you need to use the bulk API and experiment with the block size for your data.

[link to elasticsearch's documentation on bulk document indexing (importing)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html)

If you use python, take a look at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/esimport/0.1.9

Comment: Even with bulk API this was very slow. I've made this import using [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash) as I explained at my answer. Thanks for your help.